# jQuery: removing table row not working

Tags: jquery, parent, closest

I have a table with the following structure (simplified):

```
<table>
    <thead>
    // ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Text A</td><td>Text B</td><td> Text C</td><td><div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btnDel">Button Text</button></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The table rows and the buttons do not have an ID but the buttons have a class "`btnDel`". 
By click on such a button I would like to remove the corresponding row.

I tried using `$(this).closest('tr').remove();` which does not work here.

Is this the wrong approach here because there are no IDs + if so, can someone tell me the proper alternative here ?

Many thanks in advance, Tim.

Comment: It's a jQuery function fired by click on the button ($('.btnDel').on('click', function() ... ).

Comment: You're missing `<` before `div class="btn-group"`

Comment: That was just here but thanks. Updated it.

Comment: Your jQuery works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/d5m419kv/1/

Comment: Thanks, All ! I found my mistake. It was actually somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try:

```
$(this).parents("tr").first().remove();
```

?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this ! So far I have only used parent(). Can you explain in short what is the difference ?

Comment: But why? he already tried $(this).closest('tr').remove(); which will have the same effect as your code..

Comment: `parent()` only gets the immediate parent`. `parents` searches up the DOM hierarchy, returning all the matches.

Comment: while `parent(filter)` would return the first matching parent of the element, `parents(filter)` returns all of the parents which match the filter from inside out.

Comment: Thansk a lot for the explanation ! I found my mistake - it was somewhere else.

Comment: As the OP asked for an alternative, I suggested this.